# run fsck manually

Tags: linux, archlinux

перестала загружаться система. Выдает: can't access tty: job control turned off

Загружается оболочка sh. Команды fdisk, cfdisk недоступны. Каталога mnt нет.
пожалуйста, помогите.

Дистр. arch linux.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вставляйте картинку прямо в сообщение, а не ссылайтесь на внешние ресурсы. Сообщения должны быть самодостаточными, ссылки могут служить только дополнением.

Comment: `$ fsck /dev/sda3` запускали?

Comment: Mikhail, к сожалению можно вставлять только картинки с размером до 2 Мб

Comment: Вот что выдал fsck /dev/sda3 https://prnt.sc/fmgf2n

Comment: Спасибо большое, команда fsck -y /dev/sda3 помогла

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используем [fsck](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fsck_(%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9)):

`$ fsck -y /dev/sda3`

Comment: У меня встречается такая прблема раз в месяц на каком либо из серверов. Вся диагностика прходит по IPMI, лучше проводить тест в одиночном режиме - single user.